# Send notification by firebase cloud messaging on a topic by django

Tags: python, android, django, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have implemented a firebase cloud messaging app which sends a notification to an android device based on its device token which works fine. I've used django-fcm module. But, storing device registration code for each user device is a little difficult in the practical application as I've to modify the front end source code which I don't want to.

Therefor I decided to go with topic messaging. I cannot find any useful documentation regarding this.

**view.py**

```
def send_notification(registration_id,message_title, message_body):
   try:
      push_service = FCMNotification(api_key=FCM_DJANGO_SETTINGS['FCM_SERVER_KEY'])

      result=push_service.notify_single_device(registration_id=registration_id, message_title=message_title,
                                        message_body=message_body)
      return result
   except:
      pass

def send_noti(request):
    device_token = "dEMspOwATpiFVumQGi1QOS:APA91bEZsTu7SbRTYRDGJjhNhHRErYd_UHs43rrPY6uN4yXe5_UHnPpepocFP60wnnU2IImCBXcem0rVuEUj7PCPc9EfkC0W4cLrNSmBCoWM5mz8jp9YgYF-VurJ1JyoRH627IH5Ujxn"
    send_notification(device_token,"title","body")
    return JsonResponse({"status": "success"}, safe=False)
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('noti/', views.send_noti, name='send_noti'),
]
```

Can anyone help to send notification on topic using django?

Comment: https://github.com/xtrinch/fcm-django#sending-messages-to-topic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks FrankvanPuffelen for your help

The complete implementation is as follows.

**views.py**

from fcm_django.fcm import fcm_send_topic_message

```
def send_noti_topic(self):
    fcm_send_topic_message(topic_name='NEWYORK_WEATHER', message_body='message body', message_title='title')
    return JsonResponse({"status": "success"}, safe=False)
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('noti/', views.send_noti_topic, name='send_noti_topic'),
]
```

Comment: Hello @Salah, I am also facing the same issue. When I call device api, it assks for registration_id...Will your answer send the notifications to all users? What is the scene??

Comment: Hi @Reactoo, Yes. It will send to all devices where the same topic has been subscribed.